# How to use webbrowser.open() with request in python

Tags: python, django, post, browser

I made a `local GUI` which requires the users to enter their usernames and passwords. Once they click submit, I want to have a pop out window which directs them to a website with their personal information through `POST`, which requires a request. I know that there is `webbroswer.open()` to open a website, but it doesn't take any requests, how would I be able to do what I want it to do? I am using `django 1.6` and `python 2.7`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution #1)

skip all this and see Rjzheng's link below -- it's much simpler.

Solution #2)

Since `webbrowser.open()` doesn't take POST args:

1) write a javascript page which accepts args via GET, then does an Ajax POST

2) have `webbbrowser.open()` open URL from step #1

Not glamorous, but it'll work :)

Be careful with security, you don't want to expose someone's password in the GET URL!

Comment: I sort of understand the concept and I know that it's the right way, but I'm having trouble implementing it to my code, do I make a new js file?

Comment: yes. The server serves a HTML page, which is mostly javascript. The JS code then picks up the GET args (which were specified in the webbrowser.open URL), translates them into a POST, then uses Ajax to execute the POST.
It's not fun, but it'll get the job done.

Comment: http://everydayscripting.blogspot.com/2009/09/python-jquery-open-browser-and-post.html
I saw this while looking for a solution on google, is this like what you are saying?

Comment: @Rjzheng oh!  That's *way* easier than my suggestion -- thanks!  The linked page is just setting up a `<FORM>` prefilled with values, then automatically submitting it after the page loads.  The submit is a `POST`. No Ajax nor JS needed!

Comment: I'm not trying to use any Jquery, is there anyways to use JavaScript and only JavaScript for it?

Comment: follow the `everydayscripting` link you sent, that'll do it without jQuery

Comment: I'm fairly new to this so i don't quiet understand =/ Will you give me a little step by step if you don't mind?

Comment: I have nothing to add to the web page, sorry.